# plink command to print free|grep "Mem:"

Tags: command-line, free

I like to print only one "Mem:" line in the output using plink command.

plink -batch user@192.168.91.12 -P 22 -pw test@123  (free;) --> **working**

```
                      total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:               8182004    7137528    1044476      0      284648    4852520 
    -/+ buffers/cache: 2000360    6181644
    Swap:              16386260    188       16386072
```

plink -batch user@192.168.91.12 -P 22 -pw test@123  (free|grep "Mem:";) -->**not working**

above command not printing the output & terminated without any error. What's wrong in the syntax?

Comment: ok changed as per your advice

Comment: What is  plink? Googling, I get some genomics tools as the top results.

Comment: @muru Part of PuTTY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to run the `grep` remotely.

```
plink -batch user@192.168.91.12 -P 22 -pw test@123 free | grep "Mem:"
```

Note that you should not give the command to `plink` inside a subshell, `( ... )`.

I don't know anything about Windows' `cmd.exe`, but you could also try

```
plink -batch user@192.168.91.12 -P 22 -pw test@123 sh -c "free | grep 'Mem:'"
```

Comment: Since `(free;)` worked for them, I'm guessing they didn't run it in bash, zsh or dash (all of which complain about the parentheses). Given it's part of Putty, probably they ran it from cmd.exe or powershell. So piping the output outside of plink might not work as expected. (Not sure of the semantics of pipes in cmd.exe)

Comment: @muru In that case, it's not a Unix problem.

Comment: any other way to run  free|grep Mem:  from cmd.exe

Comment: Great!!! now working... thanks for your great support mate